# How to save device token from FCM in Ionic2

Tags: angular, cordova, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

I am using FCM plugin to do push notification for ionic2.
reference : https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-fcm34

I followed https://github.com/edismooth/ionic2-firebase/tree/master42

It works fine and I can received the push from firebase console. Now I want to build my own server to let admin to send push notification with own backend.

I faced one problem is : I can get the device token, however, I have no idea how to save it. Below is my code to get token:

```
initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      StatusBar.styleDefault();

       FCMPlugin.getToken(
                function (token) {
                    console.log(token); //I can successfully get the token, but I don't know how to return it.
                    alert(token);
                },
                function (err) {
                    console.log('error retrieving token: ' + err);
                }
            );
```

I have tried many methods like "return value", "store to a valuable"; however, I still have no idea how to get it out from the "FCMPlugin.getToken" function.

Anyone can help? thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can use arrow functions, like this:

```
initializeApp() {

    // ...

    FCMPlugin.getToken(
       (token) => { this.saveToken(token); },
       (err) => { this.showError(err); }
    );

    // ...

}

// ...

private saveToken(token: string): void {
    // Save the token in the storage...
}

private showError(error: any): void {
    // Show the error to the user
}
```

The difference is that now you're using **arrow functions** and...

> An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function
>   expression and **does not bind its own this**, arguments, super, or
>   new.target.

So when you use `this` inside of an arrow function, it will still reference the component instance (and not the current function).

Answer (score 0):

In your `login()` function you can use this code

```
this.push.register().then((t: PushToken) => {
  return this.push.saveToken(t);
}).then((t: PushToken) => {
  console.log('Token saved:', t.token);
});
```

When users logged in your app you can save their device token...